# Probability of percentage matching

Tags: probability, statistics

Hi I'm working with probability as part of an engineering course, and I'm struggling with the following tutorial question.

> A company has received three lots of a product, $A$, $B$, and $C$. We know that in one of them $10\%$ of the product is defective, on another $5\%$ of the product is defective and on the third $3\%$ is defective. We do not know however the matching for those percentages. In an attempt to have a better understanding we take one product from each lot. The product from $A$ is defective and the products from $B$ and $C$ are non-defective. What are the probabilities for lot $A$ to have a defective percentage of $10\%$, $5\%$ and $3\%$ respectively? Calculate the same for lots $B$ and $C$.

I tried using Bayes Theorem but nothing I did seemed to yield a logical answer.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about *how* you tried to use Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: In Bayes I thought of each plot as the mutually exclusive event and the choosing of the product as the event within the sample space and tried to work my way backwards from that. I also thought of using distributions fot calculating the probabilities for each event [ P(10%), P(5%), P(3%)] but i had trouble as to what to put for the numbers of sample, successes and population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six cases:

$A$ is $10\%$ lot, $B$ is $5\%$ lot and $C$ is $3\%$ lot.

$A$ is $10\%$ lot, $C$ is $5\%$ lot and $B$ is $3\%$ lot.

$B$ is $10\%$ lot, $A$ is $5\%$ lot and $C$ is $3\%$ lot.

$B$ is $10\%$ lot, $C$ is $5\%$ lot and $A$ is $3\%$ lot.

$C$ is $10\%$ lot, $A$ is $5\%$ lot and $B$ is $3\%$ lot.

$C$ is $10\%$ lot, $B$ is $5\%$ lot and $A$ is $3\%$ lot.

The first case have $10\%\cdot95\%\cdot97\%$ to give our result, similarly for the remaining cases.

So Essentially our probability is just

$\Large{2(10\%\cdot95\%\cdot97\%)\over2(10\%\cdot95\%\cdot97\%)+2(5\%\cdot90\%\cdot97\%)+2(3\%\cdot90\%\cdot95\%)}$

Comment: So if I am getting this. For the probability for $A$ to be the $10\%$ lot i will just calculate the 2 cases that match this and do similarly for the rest?

Comment: Yes you are right. The denominators will always be the same (the sum of all six cases) and the numerator will just be cases that match what the question is asking.